# Почему в устойчивом выражении "ни за что" пишется усилительная частица НИ?

Tags: частица-не, ни

Частица ***НЕ*** используется для отрицания, а частица ***НИ*** усиливает отрицание, обозначенное частицей НЕ. Например: *Я **не** пойду! **Ни** за что **не** пойду.*

Но почему устойчивое выражение ***НИ ЗА ЧТО*** (= зря, просто так, без причины) применяется в **утвердительных** предложениях: *Поневоле ты идешь? Аль с охоты? Ваня, Ваня, пропадешь **Ни за что** ты* (Д. Бедный).

Возможный вариант: ***не за что, а зря.***  Но мы пишем: ***ни за что.***

**[Устойчивое сочетание НИ ЗА ЧТО](https://phraseology.academic.ru/14016/%D0%9D%D0%B8_%D0%B7%D0%B0_%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE)**

**НИ ЗА ЧТО́**. Разг. Экспрес. 1. **Зря, без всякой причины**. — Нет, тебе несдобровать! Женишься — ни за что пропадёшь (Пушкин. Капитанская дочка). — Не пойду. Она ведьма у неё — нечистая сила. Пропадёшь ни за что (Ф. Гладков. Повесть о детстве) — Поди-ка пни лошадь ни за что, думаешь, не обидится? (Д. Фурманов. Красный десант). **2. Ни при каких условиях.** [Князь:] Вы, кажется, намерены простить мне долг?! Ни за что! Карточный долг — долг чести (А. Н. Толстой. Касатка)

**Примеры**

*И они тебя любят и уважают. **Ни за что**... Просто за то, что ты человек, за то, что ты гость.*

*Под Кенигсберг прибыли, когда он уже весь был разбит и почти полностью захвачен, так что и медалю мне выдали, считай что **ни за что.***

Comment: И они тебя любят и уважают. Ни за что... Просто за то, что ты человек, за то, что ты гость. - выглядит противоречиво.

Comment: Не за что употребляется когда я это делаю, не для чего. А ни за что, когда я так делать не буду, не делай так и тп. поэтому "И они тебя любят и уважают. Ни за что... Просто за то, что ты человек, за то, что ты гость." выглядит странно, как будто они тебя не уважают. Тут должно писать "не за что". У Бедного иначе, у него смысл "Ваня, не пропадай." - не ходи иначе пропадешь.

Comment: Под Кенигсберг прибыли, когда он уже весь был разбит и почти полностью захвачен, так что и медалю мне выдали, считай что ни за что. - тут верно, выдали ни за что, лучше бы не выдавали, не за что мне выдавать медаль. Короче "ни за что" дополняет уже содержащееся отрицание в тексте.

Answer (score 0):

**Ответ на комментарий**

**Интересное мнение**, есть что обсудить (жаль, что не в поле ответа).

Обратите внимание на словарную статью, там **два значения**:

(1) **Зря, без всякой причины**. — Нет, тебе несдобровать! Женишься — ни за что пропадёшь (Пушкин. Капитанская дочка). (2)  **Ни при каких условиях**.  Ни за что! Карточный долг — долг чести (А. Н. Толстой. Касатка).

Второе значение действительно усилительное: ***ни за что не прощу.*** А вот первое значение утвердительное, причем это **наречное** значение (зря, даром, без причины), падежного управления нет.

2. **Рассмотрим примеры:**

(1) ***И они тебя любят и уважают. Ни за что*** (= без причины).  Просто за то, что ты человек, за то, что ты гость.

Выглядит странно, а почему? Потому что вы видите там отрицание: *уважают **за что-то** — не уважают никогда и **ни за что***. А нужно просто воспринимать цельное значение фразеологизма.

(2) ***Пропадешь ни за что*** (= даром). Не пропадай ни за что?  Но вроде бы падежного управления нет. Не пропадай ни в коем случае? Но это уже домысливание.

(3) ***Дали медаль ни за что*** (= без причины). Дали за что? — Не дали бы ни за что. Опять звучит странно.

3. **Вывод**

Как только мы уходим от **цельного понимания** фразеологизма, то сочетание кажется странным. И это именно из-за **усилительного**  значения ***НИ***. Ведь могло бы утвердится сочетание ***не за чтО***, оно ближе по смыслу. Но частица ***НИ*** потеснила отрицательную частицу ***НЕ***.

**А на каком основании?**

Comment: не "не дали ни за что". А лучше бы не давали медали, а то дали ни за что. Не подразумевается в контексте. Ни за что как отдельная фраза-предложение - это странно. То есть вы предлагает фразеологизмы выделять в отдельные предложение и считаете такой текст согласованным? У вас 2 предложение противоречит первому, а третье противоречит первому и второму. Потому что гостей не любят, это гости, делают вид что любят, да, а второму, потому что причина таки есть, почему уважают, то есть опровергается и второе.

Comment: Нет, можно конечно сочинять тексты, в которых каждое последующее предложение опровергает понятия введенные предыдущими. Но это странно, для текста примера употребления фраз или понятий.

Comment: Ни уже подразумевает наличие не, которое можно опровергнуть - это моя идея. А НЕ, в свою очередь, это опровержение некоторого утверждение и утверждение другого. Дали медаль ни за что - я не знаю причин почем мне дали эту медаль, медали дают за взятие городов, а мы когда пришли, там уже нечего было брать, мы даже не сражались, просто посмотрели и отступили. Даже не оборонялись. За что мне дали медаль? медаль мне давать не за что, но дали - ни за что.

Comment: Переходим на отрицание. Гостей  не любить и не уважать! Медали никому не давать! Ни за что не давать. потому что не за что давать.  // Но лучше перестроить сознание, как при переходе с русских букв на латиницу. Щелк!  И вместо НИ ЗА ЧТО вы видите  "зря, без причины, просто так".  Отличный способ!  https://www.cluber.com.ua/lifestyle/psihologiya-lifestyle/2019/07/neobychnyj-test-vy-vidite-utku-ili-krolika/  А вы кого сначала видите, зайца  или утку?

Comment: Это не дает перестройку) Вы кстати привели ссылку на украинский сайт, раз мы тут о национальных вопросах заговорили) Я вижу пятна и/или контуры/черты, но если присмотреться и подумать, то можно увидеть еще что-то, а если хорошо присмотреться, можно увидеть, что это искусство - то есть это **не** заяц и **не** утка - **ни**кто из них. Тут снайпер какой-то сказал в видосе на ютубе, что человек видит - овал, треугольник, квадрат). Если границы простых фигур размыть, то человек ослепнет - в этом смысл маскировки. Это к тому кто что видит.

Comment: Так что вопрос также в том, как мы смотрим, а не только в том, что видим. Видеть что - это как раз семантика. И семантику можно видеть сперва или глубже. И семантикой все не ограничивается. Понимаете, опираясь только лишь на семантику, вы попадаете в цепочку связанных абстракций - означаемых без означаемое, ассоциативный ряд без конца и начала. Однако есть принципы формирования ассоциаций, и кроме того есть слова вещи - конкретные, а есть слова понятия - абстрации.

Comment: Любить - это очень общий глагол и по сути понятие, на самом деле он не означает почти ничего, кроме какой-то связи. Если полагаться на семантику лишь, то можно все глаголы сводить к глаголу любить. Точнее это будет так получаться. В этом проблема. Семантика не дружит с границами. Точнее семантические алгоритмы не дружит. А вот если досконально разбирать каждую фразу, то можно найти эти границы и от них исходить. Однако кроме границ есть еще принципы. Принципы - это как как отдельные планеты. Одно дело когда ассоциации в одной системе, а другое дело когда идет смешение стилей.

Comment: Стили семантика тоже с трудом определяет. Потому что семантика - это про связи, а не про границы и принципы. В семантике все со всем связано в той или иной степени, в том или ином процентном отношении, разница только в количестве, а качества в семантике просто нет.

Comment: Вы хотели лекцию, вот вам лекция)

Comment: Спасибо, Буратиночка! Не исключено, что я что-нибудь пойму из того, что вы сказали.  Но мне нужен центр, откуда остальные ваши аксиомы следуют. Вы можете его назвать?  А то я вижу только цепочки отдельных фраз – ни утки, и ни зайца))

Comment: Ты еси бог, творяй чудеса.